# Creating a note section

Tags: footnotes

I'm wondering how I can create a note section like in the picture with two lines. I would love if I can use it as a command in LaTeX like `\note{some text}`.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could post what you've tried?

Comment: What does your question have to do with biblatex or marginnote?

Comment: So far I have tried using 
`
\begin{lstlisting}
Note: Some text  end{lstlisting}  `

Comment: Using what, exactly?

Comment: The lstlisting package. But that package is more for larger amount of code and have it formatted to display a gray background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An inevitable `tcolorbox` solution, providing a lot of configuration possibilities. 
The default shift of the `Note:` is set to `1.5cm`, but this can be changed by the option `nodeshift=...`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mynote}{+O{}+m}{%
  \begingroup
  \tcbset{%
    noteshift/.store in=\mynote@shift,
    noteshift=1.5cm
  }
  \begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter,
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    toprule=1pt,
    bottomrule=1pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    colback=yellow!20,
    #1,
    left skip=\mynote@shift,
    right skip=\mynote@shift,
    overlay={\node[right] (mynotenode) at ([xshift=-\mynote@shift]frame.west) {\textbf{Note:}} ;},
    ]
    #2
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\mynote{Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again at the other end}

% Exaggerated example
\mynote[noteshift=4cm,colback=green!40]{Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again at the other end}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The king of tcolorbox :-). Very nice and I have appreciated also your answer.

Comment: Thank you. That was the best solution for me!

Comment: @user3874252: You're welcome. Happy TeXing... but please don't use the green color example ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Haha, yeah it will be colorless but I liked how you fixed the margins real nice. Thank you, again!

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful. How can we change the word {Note:} if we want in the calling inside the document? for example I may use sometimes {Note:} or {Observation:} or {Tip:} ....

Comment: Thanks. If I need to specify the title in the calling code to change the word "Note" to another one, or make instead a small icon,is it possible (as in lecture books)

Answer (score 9):

Is this something that you were looking for ?

[image]

Then you can use the **new command** `\notte` derived from the environment `quote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\Lnote}
\newcommand{\notte}[1]
     {\addtolength{\leftmargini}{4em}
        \settowidth{\Lnote}{\textbf{Note:~}}
        \begin{quote}
            \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\leftmargini}{1pt}\\
                        \mbox{}\hspace{-\Lnote}\textbf{Note:~}%
                                            #1\\[-0.5ex] 
            \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\leftmargini}{1pt}
        \end{quote}
        \addtolength{\leftmargini}{-4em}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[3]

        \notte{To create a note section like in the picture, use the command \texttt{notte}.}

    \lipsum[4]

        \notte{Another note}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good and I have appreciated your work.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks.  However, I was wondering how to set the left and right margins differently-- `\leftmargini` controls the left margin within a quote very much as its right margin too... and there apparently seems to be no `\rightmargini` !

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `tabularx, makecell`  and `linegoal`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, linegoal}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for example text

\newcommand{\mynote}[1]{\medskip\par\textbf{\small Note}\quad\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}\begin{tabularx}{\linegoal}{X}
\Xhline{1pt}
\rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!80!Lavender}#1 \\
\Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}}

    \begin{document}
\sffamily
    \lipsum[2]

\mynote{Internal pullup resistors are enabled on the MSP430F20xx to support l\textsuperscript{2}C communication}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try footnote. There should be an understanding in the text, as to the note points to which text (like references). Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World
This is text with a note.\footnote{This is the note text.
Here it is at the bottom of the page.}
\end{document}
```

[image]